# Why does `apt-get -f install` tell me that 141 packages were not updated?

Tags: apt, package-management

When I run `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done(
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 141 not upgraded.
```

What are these 141 packages that need to be upgraded?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though this is due to dependencies. From a debian page which can be found [here](https://debian-administration.org/article/69/Some_upgrades_show_packages_being_kept_back);

> If the dependencies have changed on one of the packages you have
>   installed so that a new package must be installed to perform the
>   upgrade then that will be listed as "kept-back".

According to the Debian page above running the command

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Will address the issue you are having, this could cause broken functionality but I image it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is

```
apt-get install pkgs
```

You did not specify any package, so none was updated.
You want to do

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```